# django extended page not rendering values from registration page (User django Model)

Tags: django

I extended the user model and created one to one relationship from users to a Customer model. However, whenever I'm calling the Customer Page the fields from the user model are not rendered there. It's only rendering one field, the username in the Customer Model in the field name instead of rendering the first name as name, last name and email address, and so on. How can I achieve that? I need the customer form to fill in using information from the user's registration whichever is available. Makes sense? Or the implementations I'm trying to do is wrong. Thank you in advance. Please see below the code for models.py and views.py

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
        #return self.name



# Using signals to post_save data

def customer_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
        instance.groups.add(group)
        Customer.objects.create(
            user=instance,
            name=instance.username,
            )
        print('Profile created!')

post_save.connect(customer_profile, sender=User)
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
#from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required # in order to restrict views, login decorators

# Create your views here.
from .models import *
from .forms import CreateUserForm, EditProfileForm, CustomerForm
from .decorators import unauthenticated_user, allowed_users, admin_only
def home(request):
    return render(request,'first_app/home.html')
def books(request):
    return render(request,'first_app/books.html')

@unauthenticated_user
def registerPage(request):

    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm (request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')

            #group = Group.objects.get(name ='customer') # replaced with signals on models.py
            #user.groups.add(group)
            #Customer.objects.create(
            #user=user,
            #name=user.username,
            #)

            messages.success(request,'Hello ' + username + ' Your account has been created')
            return redirect('login')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'first_app/register.html', context)

@unauthenticated_user
def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('profile')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or Password is Incorrect')
            messages.info(request, 'Please Try Again')
    context = {}
    return render(request,'first_app/login.html', context)

def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

@login_required(login_url='login') # in order to restrict views, login decorators
def profile(request):
    #contex = {}
    return render(request,'first_app/profile.html')

def base(request):
    #contex = {}
    return render(request,'first_app/base.html')

@login_required(login_url='login') # in order to restrict views, login decorators
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'first_app/edit_profile.html', args)

def userPage(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'first_app/user.html', context)


@login_required(login_url='login') # in order to restrict views, login decorators
def customer(request):
    #customers = Customer.objects.all()
    #context = {'customers':customers} # dictionary to passing the data below

    customer = request.user.customer # using customer instance
    form = CustomerForm(instance=customer) # using customer instance
    #user = request.user
    #form = CustomerForm(instance=user)


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=customer) # using customer instance
        #form = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()


    context = {'form':form}

    return render(request, 'first_app/customer.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

from .models import *

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    #fullname = forms.CharField(label="First name")
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'] #Python list

class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    #fullname = forms.CharField(label="First name")
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username', 'email'] #Python list

class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
```

Comment: can you add the code for CustomerForm from your forms.py file please

Comment: I just posted forms.py  Thank you

Comment: You don't need the line `fields = '__all__'` if you've included exclude. Try removing that line and see what happens

Comment: No luck. Still the same. Just grabbing the username into Name.

Comment: As another test, if you change the line `form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)` in the customer view function to a blank form, `form = CustomerForm()` does it render all the empty fields?

Comment: Yes, it did remove the username field on the Name field. All fields are blank now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228086/discussion-between-danoram-and-nick-nick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the long post..

I tried looking for a built in solution from django but I couldn't find one.

The simplest thing I could think of was to just have two models in the form itself.

This requires removing some of the fields from the `Customer` model that already exist in the User model. I also didn't use the `customer_profile` post_save signal. So these suggestions are untested with it unless it is fully redundant with the changes which may be so.

modified in `models.py`

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

Then of course a reminder to run migrations

```py
python manage.py makemigrations first_app
python manage.py migrate
```

If they fail delete the migrations folder and the database file and run again (assuming the database doesn't contain any data worth keeping).

## If you want to present the user's data to them but not have them be able to edit it then you need to add a model form in the following way.

added to `forms.py`

```py
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': True }),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': True }),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': True }),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': True }),
        }
        help_texts = {
            'username': ''
        }
```

The fields are set to readonly and not disabled because otherwise they won't be submitted with the form. The annoying help text is also disabled for the `username` field.

Then your `customer` view can look like this

`views.py`

```py
# add these imports
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# add UserForm
from .forms import CreateUserForm, EditProfileForm, CustomerForm, UserForm

@login_required(login_url='login') # in order to restrict views, login decorators
def customer(request):

    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # create customer
        customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST)

        # check if customer already exists
        # this allows customer details to be edited
        # also stops unique key error if creating a customer for a user that already has a customer object
        try:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(user=user)
            customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=customer)
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST)

        if customer_form.is_valid():
            customer = customer_form.save(commit=False)
            customer.user = user
            customer.save()

        # returning HttpResponse else you will reload the same page
        return HttpResponse("Successfully saved Customer")
        
    user_form = UserForm(instance=user)

    customer_form = CustomerForm()

    context = {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'customer_form': customer_form 
        }

    return render(request, 'first_app/customer.html', context)
```

I don't know what your `customer.html` page looks like but the following html will give the corresponding output.

`customer.html`

```html
<h1>Customer Page</h1>

<form action="/customer" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ user_form.as_p }}

    {{ customer_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Create Customer"></input>
</form>
```

test user in User table
[image: test user in db]

the rendered form with the relevant fields pre-populated.

[image: rendered form with all fields]

The resulting `Customer` object in the database

[image: Customer object in db]

## If you want the customer to be able to edit their user data then do the following instead after changing the `Customer` model.

added to forms.py

```py
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email'
        ]
```

views.py

```py
@login_required(login_url='login') # in order to restrict views, login decorators
def customer(request):

    user = request.user

    if request.method == 'POST':

        # update user
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()

        # safety check if customer already exists
        # this allows customer details to be edited
        # also stops unique key error if creating a customer for a user that already has a customer object
        try:
            customer = Customer.objects.get(user=user)
            customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST, instance=customer)
        except Customer.DoesNotExist:
            customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST)

        # create customer
        customer_form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if customer_form.is_valid():
            customer = customer_form.save(commit=False)
            customer.user = user
            customer.save()



        # returning HttpResponse else you will reload the same page
        return HttpResponse("Successfully saved Customer")
        
    user_form = UserForm(instance=user)

    customer_form = CustomerForm()

    context = {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'customer_form': customer_form 
        }

    return render(request, 'first_app/customer.html', context)
```

customer.html (same as previous example)

```html
<h1>Customer Page</h1>

<form action="/customer" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ user_form.as_p }}

    {{ customer_form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Create Customer"></input>
</form>
```

example update of user details in form

[image: rendered form with edited user details]

the updated user in the database
[image: updated user]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much! Let me test it and I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Think this way.

Django default `User` model has:

```
['first_name','last_name','username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

You don't have to store them again in `Customer` model, instead you can update them.

Remove these below fields in `Customer` model:

```
['name','last_name', 'email']
```

So your `Customer` model will be like:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    address_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)
```

Then your `customer_profile` signal will be like:

```
def customer_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='customer')
        instance.groups.add(group)
        Customer.objects.create(
            user=instance,
            )
        print('Profile created!')

post_save.connect(customer_profile, sender=User)
```

Now you have two pages.
One is for `edit profile` page for updating values:

```
['first_name','last_name','username', 'email']
```

Other is for filling `Customer` model fields:

```
['phone','city','address_1', 'zip_code']
```